# Error trying to compile Monero on Fedora 25 - makefile:62: recipe for target 'release-all' failed

Tags: compile

When trying to compile the latest Monero on Fedora 25, I'm getting this error. When I run make, this is all the output below. I double-checked and I have all the dependencies...cmake is installed.

`mkdir -p build/release
cd build/release && cmake -D BUILD_TESTS=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release ../.. && make
/bin/sh: cmake: command not found
Makefile:62: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
make: *** [release-all] Error 127`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `cmake`, one of the prerequisites for building Monero. cmake is a build tool, which can be installed on Fedora this way:

`sudo dnf install cmake`

Once cmake is installed, try `make` again.

Since you say cmake is installed, then it is either manually installed somewhere not in your PATH, or some of it is corrupted, or it is not actually installed. If you think it's installed, install it again. Or remove it, then install again. To check if cmake is installed:

`which cmake`

It might be that a non default version of cmake might be installed, then it might be called something like `cmake-x.y`. Try typing just `cmake` then TAB twice to attempt to autocomplete to a command in your PATH.

Comment: Thank for the thorough answer. You were right that cmake was not installed... thought it was there but was mistaken. Also found that I need the dev versions of some of the other dependencies. Thanks again for the help